# Return null value or numberic value of 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm needing to return values in SQL query that are either null or 2 for broker reason codes.  I've tried using a.BROKER_REASON in (2,null), but it only pulls back 2's.  I've tried using "a.BROKER_REASON  is null or a.BROKER_REASON = 2" and get error msg "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '+MULTI' to data type int."  Is there an easy way to return rows with null values or values of 2?

Comment: `a.BROKER_REASON is null or a.BROKER_REASON = '2'`

Answer (score 0):

That error looks more like your value stored isn't an actual number but rather a small string.

Try:

```
a.BROKER_REASON is null or a.BROKER_REASON = '2'
```

If not you may have extra spaces there stored, and can happen depending on storage engines/table definitions, in which case you can do a `LTRIM` or `LEFT` (depends on what SQL database you use) or equivalent to trim off excess spaces.